# Creating auto confirmation , with jquery and javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome, firefox

i just created a function automatically reserve appointment
its work perfectly on jsFiddle
The problem Is i get errors when i past it on chrome console same as firefox

Error :

> uncaught typeerror cannot read property 'on' of 'null'

This is the Function jQ+JS:

```
(function(){
$('a.dispo').on('click', function(){
var hold= setInterval(function(){
var submitclassform = document.getElementById('ajax_confirm_action');
if (submitclassform) {
          var button = document.getElementById('ajaxConfirmCall_submit');
          button.click();
          alert("confimation success ! ");
          clearInterval(hold);
    }
    },500);
})})();
```

HTML Code :

```
<ul>
<li class="overable initialised">2018-06-12
    <a class="dispo" id ="test" type="button" href="javascript:void(0)" 
   onclick="AC">08<i>:30</i></a>
    <a class="dispo" type="button" href="javascript:void(0)" 
  onclick="AC">09<i>:00</i></a>
    <a class="dispo" type="button" href="javascript:void(0)" 
  onclick="AC">09<i>:30</i></a>
</li>
</ul>
<p>
After choosing appointment time , scenario 
Confirmation Button POP Up ! 
</p>
<form action="action.php" id="ajax_confirm_action">

 <input type="submit" name="conf" value="CONFIRMATION " 
 id="ajaxConfirmCall_submit" >
 </form>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are placing your javascript before your rendered html (i.e. in the  tag), then your script is executing prior to the DOM node being written. Because the node does not exist yet, you get the NULL error.

Try moving your javascript to the end of your document, (i.e. just before the  tag).